# Error on Raspberry Pi says 'Read-only file system'?

Tags: raspbian, linux, debian, bash, git

For reference, this is the project I'm talking about here https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror

`bash` command being referenced:

```
bash -c "$(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MichMich/MagicMirror/master/installers/raspberry.sh)"
```

When I try to run the bash command to download and install MagicMirror, I get the error:

```
Note.js installation Done!
Cloning MagicMirror...
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'MagicMirror'.: Read-only file system
```

I tried to run the bash command again, but I got an error telling me that `dpkg` was interrupted and asked me to run another command, so I ran:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and re-ran the bash command a third time, only to arrive at the error:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1).
```

Some additional information: I’m running the command as `pi` user.

I’m running Raspbian with PIXEL because when I download NOOBS to a micro SD, ‘Raspbian’ doesn’t show up as an option (even with Ethernet connected). I was assured by some people on Reddit that Raspbian with PIXEL was the same, just with a UI.

I’ve wiped and re-installed NOOBS at least four times on this micro SD card, taking about an hour each time, and all I want is a working mirror

Do I need to go about a different way of installing this software? I’m unfamiliar with Linux so any simplified version is appreciated.

Comment: Try running those commands as root `sudo whatever command`

Comment: That ought to make those commands work but won't fix whatever the underlying problem is.